# Oracle sum 1 to count by partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to, based on the first 6 columns, calculate the desired count. For each partition of user_id, session_id and orig_id, ordered by rank_agse ascending, I'd like to, starting in 1, add one every time the lag_agse column equals 'ACCESSED'. Please find it populated to illustrate what I would want in the table below.

[image]

Comment: What you described in words does not agree with what you show as desired output. You said within each partition, you must count `'ACCESSED'` when ordering **descending** by `RANK_AGSE`. So, in the very first row, why is the count 2 and not 0? Your output looks as if you want to order **ascending** by `RANK_AGSE` for the purpose of the "running count" - and then the query ***output*** is ordered by `RANK_AGSE` descending. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant ascending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for

```
select user_id, session_id, orig_id, type, lag_agse, rank_agse,
       count(case when type = 'ACCESSED' then 1 end) 
             over (partition by user_id, session_id, orig_id 
                   order     by rank_agse) as desired_count
from   your_table
order  by user_id, session_id, orig_id, rank_agse desc
;
```

See my Comment under your question regarding ascending vs descending order by `RANK_AGSE`.

Note that `count()` does the same job as summing over 1 when type is 'ACCESSED' and 0 otherwise - and it does the same job in a simpler way.

Comment: So, they key here is that order after the partition section to let Oracle know that the count has to be done only progressively for ascending rank_agses?

Comment: @JaviTorre - Yes. The sum is always a "cumulative" sum over some ordering; but by default, if you don't specify an ordering, all rows in a partition are "tied" (equal order), so the sum will be over the entire partition. You must be careful if ties are still possible even with an `order by` clause - what is the desired result then? There are various options, and all can be handled by analytic functions, but you must understand the business problem first (before ever considering "programming" a solution).

Comment: Didn't know Oracle was so powerful, I even tried with a cursor before you came up with this solution!